# Using javascript proxies to track API methods usage

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I want to log when the api AudioContext is used, so I tried to use Proxies to set traps. Is it possible or this usage is somehow protected?

Comment: No, you'll have a hard time wrapping proxies around builtin objects.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, but is that possible? Any source I could get more information for that usage?

Comment: It might be possible, depending on what globals are overwritable and when you do it. Please show us what you tried and how it did not work.